# How to improve extract xml node in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have extract with regex split method, so i want to improve my code with proper xml extract method ?
XML format,

```
<SanctionLimit>
  <SancionBy>50400003</SancionBy>
  <MinimumLimit>0.01</MinimumLimit>
  <MaximumLimit>9999999999.99</MaximumLimit>
</SanctionLimit>
```

here is what I am currently using:

```
$.each(DetailXmlData, function(indexData, objDetail) {

        var xmlResult = objDetail.ParamInfo;
        var arrSanction = [];
        var Extracted_SancBy = [];
        arrSanction = xmlResult.split("<MinimumLimit>")[0].replace("<SanctionLimit><SancionBy>", "").replace("</SancionBy><SancionBy>", ",").replace("</SancionBy>", "").split(",");

        $.each(arrSanction, function(index, value) {
            var sancLength = ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSanctionedBy.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
            for (var i = 0; i < sancLength; i++) {
                if (ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSanctionedBy.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].attributes["SanctionedByValue"].value == value) {
                    ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSanctionedBy.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        });

        txtMinimumLimit.value = xmlResult.split("</MinimumLimit>")[0].split("<MinimumLimit>")[1];
        txtMaximumLimit.value = xmlResult.split("</MaximumLimit>")[0].split("<MaximumLimit>")[1];
        txtRemarks.value = objDetail.ParamRemarks;
    });
```

Comment: Without seeing the XML and without seeing the expected result, how do you think anyone could help you? Also, read https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ and try to come up with a solution of your own first, instead of asking "please re-write this for me".

Comment: Hi m added actual xml format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its work for me,

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlResult),
        $xml = $(xmlResult);
         $($xml).each(function() {
            alert("sanctioned By:" + $(this).find("SancionBy").text())
            alert("Minimum Limit:" + $(this).find("MinimumLimit").text());
            alert("MaximumLimit Limit:" + $(this).find("MaximumLimit").text());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use jquery's parseXML method?

```
var xml = $.parseXML(xmlcontent);
xml.find("tagName").text()
```

Comment: Its object form how its identify its xml.